# Why is this code bitshifting by 0 then comparing?

Tags: c++

Code -

```
    uint32 MagicNumber;
    *LocalFileAr << MagicNumber;

    uint32 FileVersion;
    *LocalFileAr << FileVersion;

    if ((MagicNumber == LocalFileReplay::FileMagic) && (FileVersion == LocalFileReplay::FileVersion))
    {
```

Since the vars MagicNumber and FileVersion were just defined they should be 0 yes?
What is the purpose of bitshifting left by 0?
Why would the values of MagicNumber and FileVersion be non-zero in the if statement?

Comment: What is the type of `*LocalFileAr`?

Comment: TUniquePtr<FArchive>
From UE4

Comment: Then it is serialization to archive

Comment: Isn't it from the archive?
Is a value from LocalFileAr being assign to the variables?

Comment: The arrows `<<` indicates the data direction. from the variable to the archive. (similar to `cout << var` from the var to the stdout, `cin >> var` - from the stdin to var).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The values of `MagicNumber` and `FileVersion` are unknown as you have not initialised them. Formally the behaviour on reading an uninitialised `uint32` is *undefined* (the only type that must not contain a trap representation is an `unsigned char`).

And, assuming that `<<` is not overloaded, the behaviour on using `<<` with a shift amount greater than 31 is *undefined*.

Comment: And I'm pretty sure this `<<` is overloaded to perform serialization. This looks very much like Boost.Serialization code.

Comment: Looking at it some more I'm pretty sure you're right. Its deserializing a value from  the LocalFileAr into the variables (I think?)